# VM Interaction within VNet

Tags: azure, azure-networking

I have been running a web system on an Azure VM for a year or more without any problems, but traffic is now growing to the point where I want to split the functions across two VMs and have them communicate with each other.

I have created the second VM (from a restored backup of the first) and they are on the same VNet with the local network IPs of

10.0.0.4 and 10.0.0.6

So my assumptions are that

(a) these VMs should be able to communicate with each other via any protocol or port, since they are on the same VNet and hence trusted to each other, and their shared NSG is a firewall only to the outside

(b) any traffic between them is guaranteed to be private to the VNet and hence does not need encryption

Are these assumptions valid?

The types of co-operation I want to setup between them are:

1) The web application on one can use the SMTP server on the other

2) SQL Server is on both and there is Replication from a database on one to a copy on the other

But I can't get them talking to each other at all.

For example, there is no response when I open RDP to the 10.0.0.4 VM and then from a CMD window try

ping 10.0.0.6

I'm obviously missing something important here.  Why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traffic between VM's on the same is still impacted by NSG's, either from those applied to a subnet or the VM directly. There are default rules that allow traffic in and out from the same virtual network, so if you have not done anything to block these then this should allow traffic, but if you have you will need to ensure this allows the traffic you want.

As mentioned by CB_Ron, Windows firewalls will still be in effect, so you need to make sure you allow whatever you need through these.

Comment: Thanks, this was it.  I had the NSG applied separately to both VM interfaces, so it would have been filtering inter-VM traffic.  Now I have released them, and applied the NSG to the default subnet instead, everything is working as expected.  They are protected from the outside, but fully available to each other (still subject to their internal firewalls of course).

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the firewall settings on the VMs? You didn't specify the OS, but I know e.g. Windows Firewall blocks almost everything by default, especially ping, and I'm sure that Linux OSes do the same out of the box.

Comment: Ah, so the internal firewalls are still active?  I kind of had the impression that Azure delegated the firewall functions out to the NSG.  Thanks, I will check.

Comment: And good point, I actually didn't mention the OS.  It is as you suspected Windows, Server 2016.